# Even registration emails not going through - registration produces error

Tags: civievent, email

Event registrations hang for all events and then gives error whenever "send email confirmation" is set to "yes".  While it's hanging, I can see the registration went through, then it finally shows an error with "Could not find valid value for id". I posted the full error at the end of this post.

I tried Amazon SES and sendgrid, getting the same error either way. Either way, sending test emails from outbound email settings works. It just gets stuck sending the email confirmation when registering events.

I'm currently using Drupal 7.37 and CiviCRM 4.6.3.

Full error:

```
#0 /opt/bitnami/apps/drupal/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(359): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 /opt/bitnami/apps/drupal/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Request.php(95): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("Could not find valid value for id")
#2 /opt/bitnami/apps/drupal/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Registration.php(183): CRM_Utils_Request::retrieve("id", "Positive", Object(CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Register), TRUE)
#3 /opt/bitnami/apps/drupal/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Registration/Register.php(88): CRM_Event_Form_Registration->preProcess()
#4 /opt/bitnami/apps/drupal/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(455): CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Register->preProcess()
#5 /opt/bitnami/apps/drupal/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(94): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
#6 /opt/bitnami/apps/drupal/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Register), "display")
#7 /opt/bitnami/apps/drupal/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Register), "display")
#8 /opt/bitnami/apps/drupal/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(353): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display")
#9 /opt/bitnami/apps/drupal/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Core_Controller->run((Array:3), NULL)
#10 /opt/bitnami/apps/drupal/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))
#11 /opt/bitnami/apps/drupal/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#12 /opt/bitnami/apps/drupal/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(489): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#13 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("event", "register")
#14 /opt/bitnami/apps/drupal/htdocs/includes/menu.inc(519): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
#15 /opt/bitnami/apps/drupal/htdocs/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#16 {main}
```

Comment: Could you please post your CiviCRM version number and CMS?

Comment: also confirm your urls aren't jumping from www to non-www etc

Comment: Per Pete's comment - if you are starting on a https url & winding up on http or starting on a url with www & winding up on one without you might see something like this - you should ensure that your site is ALWAYS accessed with www or ALWAYS accessed WITHOUT www & that the BASEURL in your civicrm.settings.php reflects this

Comment: Thank you so much for the responses! @JonG I'm currently using Drupal 7.37 and CiviCRM 4.6.3. I'll try to figure out if the http / www is consistent and will post back.

Comment: @EileenMcNaughton - it seems to always have the www and never has https. I also checked the base url in civicrm.settings.php - it is also http with the www. Is there maybe some page that it's going to behind the scenes to send the confirmation email with the wrong address? Any other suggestions? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I know it's late, but did you find an answer to this problem?  When you register are you registering from within CiviCRM? The error is when the code is trying to get the Event ID from your http request, when you register do you see something like this in the URL bar: /admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Finfo&id=19&reset=1  (where &id=19 is the event id?) You probably configured clean_urls, right?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known, documented bug that does not seem to have a solution.  Please see ref: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17161

I am happy to help a civicrm wizard debug this :)

Also noted here:

[CiviEvent - Error when registering: Could not find valid value for id](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4793/civievent-error-when-registering-could-not-find-valid-value-for-id)

[Even registration emails not going through - registration produces error](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4033/even-registration-emails-not-going-through-registration-produces-error)

[Why is the event registration "Thank You" page generating an error?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4983/why-is-the-event-registration-thank-you-page-generating-an-error)