# Why is the event registration "Thank You" page generating an error?

Tags: civievent

After our organization updated to the latest version of CiviCRM, our users started receiving the following error after registering for events on our website:

> **Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.**
>
> Could not find valid value for id
>
> Return to home page.

The user is properly registered on our system and receives a confirmation email.  It seems to be a problem with the thank you screen.  The configuration of the thank you screen is the same as before.

Ideas?

Comment: This is a good question!  To solve your problem, we'll need to see the expanded debugging information.  In CiviCRM, please go to **Administer menu > System Settings > Debugging and Error Handling**, select "Yes" to both "Enable Debugging" and "Display Backtrace", and press "Save".  Repeat the problem that caused your error, and you'll see much a much more detailed error.  Please update this question with the expanded error and backtrace - and don't forget to disable debugging/backtrace when you're done!

Comment: I can confirm that what @Sanjay Jain is saying is true, just tested it right now. So if you are using Wordperss, check that you have properly set the base page navigating to Administer>System Settings>CMS Database Integration.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be similar to: [CiviEvent - Error when registering: Could not find valid value for id](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4793/civievent-error-when-registering-could-not-find-valid-value-for-id)

If you are using WordPress, then setting the base url might help. Copying my response to that issue below:

I was having a similar problem. I noticed the base url for WordPress was not set.

If you haven't set that, try setting that in Administer > CMS Database Integration and let us know if that fixed your issue.

Make sure the event is not the home page, that seems to cause problems with the base url.

Answer (score 1):

The most common cause for this is that the form and thanks pages are not being viewed on the same URL; CiviCRM's form handling depends on these not varying, but often (for example) a CiviCRM form displayed on `example.org` will redirect to `www.example.org` after submission.

Check that the server base URL is the same before and after your form submission. Check hostname, path, and protocol; the following are example URLs which are NOT the same.

```
http://example.org
https://example.org
http://www.example.org
https://www.example.org
http://www2.example.org
https://www2.example.org
```

If this is affecting your site, the best step to take is to ensure that your webserver is configured to make all URLs *canonical*.

By ensuring that the form can only be viewed at a single base URL, you can ensure that CiviCRM will not be redirecting a viewer to another base URL after its submission.

Comment: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2422/could-not-find-a-valid-session-key-unable-to-save-any-admin-forms and http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/the-dashboard-does-not-render are some other questions relating to canonical URLs and CiviCRM.