# Civicrm - Use profile create mode only works 50% of the time

Tags: profile, joomla, issues

I'm using CiviCRM 4.6.10 with Joomla 3.4.8

I have a profile form setup for public view for volunteers to register.

50% of the time the form works great, submits the new contact to the database, sends an email, and forwards the submitter to the thank you page.

The other 50% of the time, once submitted, it does not send an email, does not submit the contact to the database and does not forward to the thank you page. It actually just redirects to the main page of the website.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? It seems pretty random. Any help would be appreciated. And of course let me know if I left out any essential details.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Has anyone else experienced this issue? Or might have some insight as to what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: This is a bit of a FAQ :( CiviCRM has various issues when canonical URL configuration is not in place, eg ["Could not find a valid session key" errors](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2422/could-not-find-a-valid-session-key-unable-to-save-any-admin-forms/2900#2900), ["Could not find valid value for id" errors](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4983/why-is-the-event-registration-thank-you-page-generating-an-error/4984#4984) and [issues with admin screens](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/the-dashboard-does-not-render).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually able to correct this issue. The problem was: if someone accessed the site with www. in the url it worked fine. If they did it without the www, the form would not submit, but also gave no error.

On the registrar end, I just had it redirect traffic that does not enter www. to the site with www.

I hope that's clear. Thanks

Comment: Glad you found it! You've configured your site with a canonical URL, which means that CiviCRM won't be addressed at *both* example.org and www.example.org. Not having this in place can upset the form handling in some parts of CiviCRM.